# C-functions in a separate file: no previous prototype

Tags: objective-c, prototype

I am working on a project for iPhone in Obj-C with iOS 4 and Xcode 4.

In a separate file called "matrix.h" (without .m counterpart) I have several "helper" C-functions, like matrix inverse, matrix determinant and so on.

This functions are called in several other file .m but the compiler gives a warning "No previous prototype" for every functions in matrix.h.

How can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it the regular way:
Create prototypes in .h and write the implementation of the functions in a .m or .c, if it's C.

Then #import the <.h> in the files where you use these helper functions or put the #import into precompiled header file (.pch), if you use it very often.